# How to hard-code a default WCF endpoint for a service?

Tags: .net, wcf, endpoint, wcf-endpoint

In a self-hosted service, I'd like to use the endpoint(s) specified in App.config, if present, or a default endpoint specified in code if App.config is empty. How can I do this?

**Edit**: to clarify, this is on the server (service) side using ServiceHost.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to `try` the first attempt to load from the config file, and hard-code the endpoint in the `catch`. EG:

```
MyServiceClient client = null;
try
{
    client = new MyServiceClient();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    EndpointAddress defaultAddress = new EndpointAddress(...);
    Binding defaultBinding = new Binding(...);
    client = new MyServiceClient(defaultBinding, defaultAddress);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for server-side code. Might as well do it on the client too I guess :)

Comment: If it's a self-hosting service (ie: you're using ServiceHost), then the same technique will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the configuration section as below:

```
var clientSection =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
```

If value is null or if `clientSection.Endpoints` contains zero elements then it is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced to same kind of issue when I wanted to implement the standalone service client without app.config file. and Finally I could sort it out. Please follow the below code sample. It is working fine and I have tested it.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_ITaskService";
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
binding.AllowCookies = false;
binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

Uri endPointAddress = new Uri("http://www.kapanbipan.com/TaskService.svc");
ChannelFactory<taskmgr.TaskService.ITaskServiceChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITaskServiceChannel>(binding, endPointAddress.ToString());
taskmgr.TaskService.ITaskServiceChannel client = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...untested, but should work for you. It will check your configuration for any endpoints with a matching contract. You can change it to match by name, return different information, or whatever makes sense for your situation. If no matches is found, you can put logic in to create a default endpoint.

```
    public List<EndpointAddress> GetEndpointAddresses(Type t)
    {
        string contractName = t.FullName;
        List<EndpointAddress> endpointAddresses = new List<EndpointAddress>();
        ServicesSection servicesSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/services") as ServicesSection;

        foreach (ServiceElement service in servicesSection.Services)
        {
            foreach (ServiceEndpointElement endpoint in service.Endpoints)
            {
                if (string.Compare(endpoint.Contract, contractName) == 0)
                {
                    endpointAddresses.Add(new EndpointAddress(endpoint.Address));
                }
            }
        }

        if (endpointAddresses.Count == 0)
        {
            //TODO: Add logic to determine default
            endpointAddresses.Add(new EndpointAddress("Your default here"));
        }

        return endpointAddresses;
    }
```