# How to hardcode default settings for WCF client (inside a class library)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

Is there a simple way to hard code settings and apply them only if the application referencing a class library doesn't have service model settings in its app.config?

The client code calling code from the class library would be something like this:

```
ProgramUpdater programUpdater = new ProgramUpdater(@"path\\to\\my\\program"); 
if(programUpdater.HasUpdate()) 
{
    programUpdater.Update();
}
```

Comment: What does your client look like?

Comment: In this case the client is a Windows service. I want the flexibility to be able to use the class library code in a WFP or Windows Forms application later on.
The client is very simple and basically just calls a few methods on an object (in the class library) that actually contains the WCF service client.

Comment: But what is the code for the client?

Comment: See above... in HasUpdate() and Update() calls are made to the WCF Service.

Comment: I want to see the code for the WCF client in the class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think I found some suitable answers in a question when I did some additional searching on Google.

Funny it didn't come up in my initial searches.

Here it is for future reference:

[How to hard-code a default WCF endpoint for a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584299/how-to-hard-code-a-default-wcf-endpoint-for-a-service)